# Is there any way to get TOP N records from table 1 where N based on Table 2

Tags: sql

Table1

```
Rowno   name         Date
------------------------------------
1     sathish        Dec 21    
2     kumar          Dec 22
3     sathish        Dec 21
4     sathish        Dec 22
5     sathish        Dec 21
5     sathish        Dec 22
```

Table 2

```
Date          NoofTran
-----------------------
Dec22            2
Dec21            1
```

I want to get the records from `table1` based on the `table2` `nooftran` values and randomly.

On dec22nd, the number of transaction is 2 in the table 2, so two records should take it from table 1 on the respective date and it should be random case. So out of 3 records on Dec22 , two should come randomly.

What SQL query should I use?

Comment: try searching for `inner join`

Comment: Inner join will give all the records, but i want the Table 1 records based on the Table 2 nooftrans values. on Dec 22 in the table 2, the values is 2. so Two records should get it from the table 1 out of 3 records.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server you can use a cross apply like this

```
select t1.*
from Table2 as t2
cross apply
(
   select top (select T2.nooftran) *
   from Table1 as t1
   where t2.Date = t1.date
   order by newid()       
) as t1
```

---

#### Sample

```
declare @T1 table (rowno int, name varchar(max), [date] date);
declare @T2 table ([date] date, nooftran int);

insert into @T1 values 
(1, 'sathish', '2015-01-01'),
(2, 'kumar', '2016-01-01'),
(3, 'sathish', '2015-01-01'),
(4, 'sathish', '2016-01-01'),
(5, 'sathish', '2015-01-01'),
(5, 'sathish', '2016-01-01');

insert into @T2 values ( '2016-01-01', 2), ( '2015-01-01', 1);

select t1.*
from @T2 as t2
cross apply
(
   select top (select T2.nooftran) *
   from @T1 as t1
   where t2.Date = t1.date
   order by newid()       
) as t1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT rs.RowNo, rs.DATE, rs.NAME
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ROWNO, t1.DATE, t1.NAME, Rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY t1.DATE ORDER BY newid()
            ) AS Rank
    FROM table1 t1
    ) rs
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON rs.DATE = t2.DATE
WHERE Rank <= t2.NoofTran
```